# Question Appropriate for Super User

Tags: discussion

Please let me know if this question is appropriate for this community.

> **Recommendation for Connecting Multiple Wireless Headphones to a Television to Play Audio through the Television and Headphones
>   Simultaneously**
>
> ### Background
>
> My grandparents are practically deaf. In order for them to "hear"
>   sound, the television has to be close to max volume.
>
> I understand the solution is to have them wear hearing aids.
>   Unfortunately, they refuse.
>   **Is it possible to have both the audio play from the television and to wireless headphones as well?**
>
> ### Current Setup
>
> The TV Is connected to their cable box via HDMI where the TV outputs
>   sound.
>
> This is the back of their cable box [image: Back of Optimum Online Cable Box- Samsung]
>
> ---
>
> I have researched a fair amount into this and am no expert.
>
> To the best of my knowledge, it is possible to do this from a
>   **computer**, but I am not sure for a **television**.
>
> The solutions involve playing audio through HDMI through the TV as
>   well as the audio jack of the TV.
>
> -->"http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/is-it-possible-to-have-speakers-and-hdmi-play-at/4563a5f8-4be4-4463-b312-eff594a9ae49"
>
> My proposed solution was to get try and mimic the computer solution by
>   using something like this [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00BIQER0E](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BIQER0E)
>
> J-Tech Digital ® Premium Quality 1080P HDMI To HDMI + Audio (SPDIF +
>   RCA Stereo) Audio Extractor Converter
>
> - Extract the digital HDMI audio signal from the HDMI input and convert it to 2 channel analog stereo output or 5.1 channel Audio
>     output
>
>   ---
>
> My only issue with this solution, is the ability to use more than two
>   wireless headphones at the same time. I would need to connect about 6
>   wireless headphones. I was going to use these Power Acoustik Farenheit
>   HP-902 RFT headphones.
>
> **Is there a splitter or switch for the red and white audio output that would allow this?** I have seen splitters and switches that allow
>   you to switch to different inputs, but not all at the same time.
>
> I really appreciate any type of input, please correct me if said
>   something incorrect or silly.

Comment: I do not want to answer that here because 1) It is off-topic and 2) it sets a bad trend. But as someone with a parent with hearing aid and 95% hearing loss: Headphones, heck yes. If you have two people, use two wireless headphones with high level output. In my experience it just works and it does deafen the other users in the room. In our case the audio outputs on the TV are used. (Hint: check if yours has any, no need for extra hardware that way).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time out to give me some feedback. Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Nope. Questions involving consumer electronics are off topic. Cable boxes arn't in our scope.

Comment: Any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: There's no real home for questions like that