# Why was my question (relating to consumer electronics) migrated here?

Tags: support, migration

I have a question about my Super User post: [Do Ethernet over HDMI injectors exist and if so what are they called?](https://superuser.com/questions/1264707/do-ethernet-over-hdmi-injectors-exist-and-if-so-what-are-they-called)

This is something I have always found a little awkward about StackExchange in general, finding the right community to post in. I had a question about HDMI and ethernet cables, so I go through the StackExchange list looking for an appropriate community and I see:

> Electrical Engineering:
>   Q&A for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts

My question involves electronics, likely more toward the 'enthusiasts' category, but it seems fairly appropriate. A quick search of the questions there for HDMI and ethernet keywords does not yield my question, but *does* result in some [similar questions about cable hookups and adapters](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/217785/convert-bnc-to-ethernet-to-coax-hdmi).

I post the question, and shortly get a few comments saying it is inappropriate for the site, then got an excellent answer there, then someone migrates it to Superuser. Which is described as:

> Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users

Uhhh, what? From that description, I imagine this community would be all about software and maybe some computer peripherals, not about specialized cable adapters and pinouts. Some question searching here reveals a bit of an awkward relationship with the subject, there *are* [some questions about cable hookups](https://superuser.com/questions/1125035/hdmi-dvi-cable-works-on-some-monitors-but-doesnt-on-others), but there is [also a pretty flat 'no' on consumer electronics](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11961/question-appropriate-for-super-user).

Side question: Is there somewhere else I should be looking when figuring out if a question is appropriate for a community? Are there better descriptions or formalized rules posted anywhere?

Main question: Why was my post migrated? From my research I don't feel like the Superuser community is the appropriate place for the question.

Comment: Most if not all exchanges have a [on-topic (EE)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) post in their help section. [SU on-topic help](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Usually those have some more information on what kind of questions are expected.

Comment: IIRC consumer electronics are off-topic for [electronics.se]. We deal with all sorts of networking things here so I think is a better fit here.

Comment: @Seth thanks, that already clarifies a lot. I had no idea there was a help section for each community with information like that.